# Is possible, in PHP, serialize array in "human-readable language" and then unserialize it?

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization, store, human-readable

I ask serialization and unserialization by PHP script. Only sometimes I edit the array manually (in database.txt).

Comment: PHP has serialize and unserialize functions but they don't give you output in human readable language, btw  which languages give it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could export the array as a [JSON](http://json.org) (JavaScript Object Notation) string and later decode it again.

You can do this with the functions [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), respectively.

```
$a = array(
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => array(1,2,3));
file_put_contents('database.txt', json_encode($a));
// encoded: {a:1,b:2,c:[1,2,3]}

// ---
$a = json_decode(file_get_contents('database.txt'), TRUE);
// specify TRUE to parse objects as assoc. arrays ---^
```

Note, that all this might not be the best idea (I'm a bit worried about the filename you chose – if you want to have a DB, then use a DB! (e.g. sqlite)).

Comment: For the OP: `json_decode()` needs to have he second parameter set to (bool) TRUE, or the data will be decoded into a PHP object instead of an array. Personally, I'd see if your server has [YAML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php) installed first, as it's slightly easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the JSON format.  Depending on what type of data you are serializing, this should do what you want, and it's pretty human readable and easily edited.

In particular, your array is limited to containing only numbers, strings, floats, boolean values, or other arrays.  However, you can store both numerically indexed as well as associative arrays.

For more information on the standard, take a look at http://www.json.org/ and for the php functions, see https://www.php.net/json_encode and https://www.php.net/json_decode